# Searching for a pattern inside a specific filetype from a zip file

Tags: unix, grep

There is a zip file which contains around 50K files of various types.

I am interested in the below pattern match (looking for output 1150000)

```
AmountDue 1150000
```

I know that the file which contains the details is of the type .abc and there is a single occurance of .abc file

Currently , I am using this :

```
zipgrep "AmountDue"  /path/to/sample.zip
```

It is taking a considerable time (~ 5mins) to perform this search.Not sure why.
Is it possible to specify the file type to search for - .abc in this case. Something like this:

```
zipgrep "AmountDue"  /path/to/sample.zip -file_to_search=.abc
```

Any suggestions on how this can be implemented/bettered upon will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the "glob" pattern *.abc to the end of the command. Quote it to avoid expansion

```
 zipgrep "AmountDue"  /path/to/sample.zip '*.abc'
```